# Multiple callback are needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Suppose I have a script like this

```
var a = getData();

function getData() {
 if (some_condition) { // Do this }
 else {// Do this }
 return fetchFromDB(param);
}

function fetchFromDB(param) {
 db.transaction(function (tx) { 
  tx.executeSQL("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE column = ? ", [param], function (tx, res) {
   return res.rows.item(0).foo
  });
 });
}
```

Problem is tx.executeSQL is asynchronous and so fetchFromDB() method returns undefined to caller i.e getData(), same undefined is passed back to main function.
To avoid this I need to have one callback in fetchFromDB() like

```
tx.executeSQL("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE column = ? ", [param], function (tx, res) {
   callBack1(res.rows.item(0).foo);
  });
```

So now value is returned to getData() but I need to have one callback2 here to return to main function also which returns data from callback1. By this way it seems that I need to have callback for where ever I called. Certainly I am missing something here ! How can I restrict to one callback ?

Comment: @elclanrs Could you please explain a bit more.

Comment: You can't.  As you've discovered, you can only return the result of an asynchronous call via a callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using nested functions

```
function f1() {
    function f1callback(param) {
        console.log(" callback 1 " + param);
    }
    f2(f1callback);
}

function f2(callback) {
    function f2callback(param) {
        console.log(" callback 2 " + param);
        callback(param);
    }
    f3(f2callback);
}

function f3(callback) {
    function f3callback(param) {
        console.log(" callback 3 " + param);
        callback(param);
    }
    f4(f3callback);
}

function f4(callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        callback("data");
    }, 1000);
}

f1();
```

Comment: But am expecting f1() to return data, something like this http://jsfiddle.net/yN4xB/ (notice that first it will throw undefined then callbacks are called)

Comment: @2-Stroker - Callbacks don't "return" data. Callbacks *use* data. Whatever you need to do with your data, you do it in the callback - or in another function you call from the callback. The second code snippet in your question looked fine - the `callBack1` function will receive the `foo` data and do something with it. What problem are you having with that approach?

Comment: @2-Stroker : You can write a function to do all the operations using `foo` and invoke it in the callback like this - http://jsfiddle.net/yN4xB/3/